# Querying all documents(files) in folder

Tags: rest-api, document

I have a folder with lots of photos. I am trying to access the files of that specific folder, preferably via API.

I am able to query a specific document in that folder via the document endpoint with: /services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Document/{ID}

And I can also query the Folder with: "SELECT Id, FolderId, Folder.Name FROM Document"

How can I query all the documents in the folder, so that their Document ID and names will be returned?

So maybe something like: "Select Document ID, Document Name FROM Document WHERE FolderID = 'XXX'" unless I'm way off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SOQL should work if you have the Folder's Name

```
SELECT Id, Name 
  FROM Document WHERE FolderId IN 
                      (SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE DeveloperName = 'foo')
```

In REST API terms:

```
/services/data/v54.0/query?q=SELECT Id, Name FROM Document 
                               WHERE FolderId IN 
                                (SELECT Id FROM Folder WHERE DeveloperName = 'foo')
```

If you have the folder's Id

```
SELECT Id, Name 
  FROM Document WHERE FolderId = '00lxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!